# Tried Everything - Browsers Not Rendering reCAPTCHA

Tags: browser

I've got the usual browsers with Gecko and Blink engines.  Never had a problem with the
original simple version of CAPTCHA.

[image: https://pasteboard.co/HIFYAg8.gif]

If I try over and over, one of my browsers might render "I'm not a robot" followed by the 
thumbnail array of selectable images.  There are hundreds of possible fixes.  Just type
"browsers not rendering reCAPTCHA" into any search engine.  I've tried more fixes than I
can remember.  Nothing seems to work.

There are a few sites that I've used for years.  I can't login anymore because they recently
adopted reCAPTCHA.

This may be a drastic solution, but I'm looking at tiny Linux distros that can boot from
within a host operating system, like Damn Small Linux (DSL).  I'm guessing the browsers
included with these small distros will render reCAPTCHA normally.

http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/

Since nothing I've tried has fixed the reCAPTCHA problem, should I download a distro that
can launch inside Windows?

Comment: So this only occurs within your Windows operating system, linux is unaffected and "just works"?

Comment: Which browsers have you tried, and are you on Windows? Have you tried with your anti-virus disabled?

Comment: What antivirus or antimalware do you have installed? Do you use any browser "cleaners" or malware services such as Malwarebytes or Spybot Search and Destroy? Is your `hosts` file clean? What version of the operating system are you using? What browser versions?

Comment: Seeming as though many hundreds of thousands, even millions, of users who use such services that Google provide - such as their CAPTCHA - without problem then one might assume the problem is on your computer. As @Mokubai has stated, do you have any malware on your computer that may be hijacking your browser(s)? Do you have any browser add-ons that may be performing something you've wanted, with a side-effect (CAPTCHA not working) that you're unaware of? Have you tried another computer?

Answer (score -2):

On OS Windows XP, browser Firefox 47.0.2.
I've added the "User Agent Switcher" addon from:
https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/ 
downloaded the addon last list from:
https://techpatterns.com/downloads/firefox/useragentswitcher.xml 
and imported it from the addon's Options.
I deleted all cookies that refers to google and capt.
I changued on Default User Agent following this path:
Tools - Default User Agent - Mobile Devices - Browsers and I selected "Firefox 48.0 - Android 6.0.1 (Samsung SM-G935F)".
And recaptcha started working.
This is not a problem with OS, browsers or protocols.
The problem is whith Google, that restricts the access 
to some browsers and OS.

Comment: Hi. You've made a sweeping statement there. Please provide some documentation on "The problem is whith Google, that restricts the access to some browsers and OS."

Comment: The test was done on the same PC, and the only changes 
were the steps described. This means that under the same 
conditions, and only by changing the information that 
is sent to the site, in this case Google, I accessed to 
a page, the which was otherwise rejected asking for an 
update of the browser to a version that would means an 
OS update.

Comment: That does not prove that google is restricting access. All it shows is the problem is limited to that machine. There could be firewall or other similar networking elements that are causing this.

Comment: If it were a firewall it would have to be on the server with which I want to connect, 
in this case Google. But it should block my IP, not according to browser type,  
or OS that I am using. The tests were made with the same PC and IP.

Comment: no, the firewall could be on the computer with the fault. Given you've not shown this is a problem others are reporting, its highly likely the issue is on faulty pc.

Comment: If it was the computer's firewall, it should act by blocking the IP always. In this case the IP is not blocked since there is always a response, in one case saying that the browser must be updated, and in the other accepting the captcha.

Comment: Sorry, but you still aren't getting the point here. All you've shown is that the problem exists in some way on the machine in question. There is zero evidence in your answer to show that google are blocking by browser. The problem may not be a firewall... it could be ANY program on that machine. Test with other machines before making such a sweeping statement.